# Argument 1 passed to UAParser\Parser::parse() must be of the type string, null given in laravel stats tracker

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I installed [this package](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) but when I running `php artisan migrate`, I see this error:

> In Parser.php line 35:
>
> Argument 1 passed to UAParser\Parser::parse() must be of the type
>   string, null given, called in...

my code in `config/database.php`:

```
'tracker' => [
            'driver'   => 'tracker',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'strict' => false,    // to avoid problems on some MySQL installs
],
```

what is the problem?

I think the above code must be wrong.

Comment: This does'nt look like a migration error message - have you registered properly the application?

Comment: I followed this installation: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker#installing

Comment: have you run: `php artisan migrate --database=tracker`

Comment: yeah, you right. all command showing that error, also `php artisan migrate --database=tracker` or something like `php artisan route:list`

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: this time show this error:

`In Parser.php line 35:

  Argument 1 passed to UAParser\Parser::parse() must be of the type string, null given, called in E:\server\xampp\htdocs\laravel-projects\ansariha\vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Support\UserAgentPar
  ser.php on line 25


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1`

Comment: can you `dd($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];)` anywhere in your code?

Comment: try to put `ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');` at the beginning of your `public\index.php` - this is not a permanent solution obviously but should fix the issue for now.. Please wait for the package update following the github issue

Comment: "PostmanRuntime/7.24.1"

Comment: I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the package that needs fixing to be able to work.  A quick workaround would be to set the user_agent manually by php if absent:

You can add the following at the beginning of your public\index.php temporarily:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');
```

Comment: i use this project for rest-api, but tnx for help

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue in the package that needs fixing to be able to work. The error occurs when `composer dump-autoload` runs.

So I edited the `pragmarx\tracker\src\Support\UserAgentParser.php` and edit the `construct` method.

Here is my code:

```
public function __construct($basePath, $userAgent = null)
    {
        $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        if (!$userAgent && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            $userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        }

        $this->parser = Parser::create()->parse($userAgent);

        $this->userAgent = $this->parser->ua;

        $this->operatingSystem = $this->parser->os;

        $this->device = $this->parser->device;

        $this->basePath = $basePath;

        $this->originalUserAgent = $this->parser->originalUserAgent;
    }
```

After that, I run `composer dump-autoload` my self.

**NOTE:** Of course when you run `composer update` or `composer install` this error occur again

Comment: i think this is a bug.

Comment: Works, but it's not the proper solution.

Comment: I saw an issue raised the the repository here: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker/issues/503

Answer (score 0):

Search for this file `pragmarx\tracker\src\Support\UserAgentParser.php` and add the line below at the start of construct method.

```
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```