# Laravel composer TypeError during installation

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a little problem with my composer.
I'm using laragon on windows so everything is 'made' for me.

I've installed using `composer require pragmarx/tracker`  command, and it was fine.
But because I'm a bit stupid I thought it was causing some problems so I've removed it with `composer remove pragmarx/tracker`. Now I want to reinstall it, but I got the following problem.

I can't find a solution anywhere, and I don't really understand the problem.

```
C:\laragon\www\Portfolio (master)
λ composer require pragmarx/tracker
Using version ^4.0 for pragmarx/tracker
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 12 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing jaybizzle/crawler-detect (v1.2.96): Loading from cache
  - Installing snowplow/referer-parser (0.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing pragmarx/datatables (v1.4.12): Loading from cache
  - Installing composer/ca-bundle (1.2.7): Loading from cache
  - Installing ua-parser/uap-php (v3.9.13): Loading from cache
  - Installing mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib (2.8.34): Loading from cache
  - Installing jenssegers/agent (v2.6.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing pragmarx/support (0.9.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/event-manager (1.1.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/cache (1.10.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (2.10.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing pragmarx/tracker (v4.0.0): Loading from cache
snowplow/referer-parser suggests installing symfony/yaml (Support for YAML configuration file)
ua-parser/uap-php suggests installing symfony/yaml (Required for CLI usage - ^3.4 || ^4.3 || ^5.0)
ua-parser/uap-php suggests installing symfony/filesystem (Required for CLI usage - ^3.4 || ^4.3 || ^5.0)
pragmarx/support suggests installing symfony/yaml (The Yaml class needs it)
doctrine/cache suggests installing alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter (Required to use legacy MongoDB driver)
pragmarx/tracker suggests installing geoip/geoip (~1.14)
pragmarx/tracker suggests installing geoip2/geoip2 (~2.0)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   TypeError

  Argument 1 passed to UAParser\Parser::parse() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\laragon\www\Portfolio\vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Support\UserAgentParser.php on line 25


  at C:\laragon\www\Portfolio\vendor\ua-parser\uap-php\src\Parser.php:37
    33|         $this->userAgentParser = new UserAgentParser($this->regexes);
    34|     }
    35|
    36|     /** Sets up some standard variables as well as starts the user agent parsing process */
  > 37|     public function parse(string $userAgent, array $jsParseBits = []): Client
    38|     {
    39|         $client = new Client($userAgent);
    40|
    41|         $client->ua = $this->userAgentParser->parseUserAgent($userAgent, $jsParseBits);

  1   C:\laragon\www\Portfolio\vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Support\UserAgentParser.php:25
      UAParser\Parser::parse()

  2   C:\laragon\www\Portfolio\vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider.php:174
      PragmaRX\Tracker\Support\UserAgentParser::__construct("C:\laragon\www\Portfolio")
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

EDIT 1:

The result of `composer dump-autoload` is:

```
composer dump-autoload
Generating optimized autoload files> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   TypeError

  Argument 1 passed to UAParser\Parser::parse() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\laragon\www\Portfolio\vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Support\UserAgentParser.php on line 25

  at C:\laragon\www\Portfolio\vendor\ua-parser\uap-php\src\Parser.php:37
    33|         $this->userAgentParser = new UserAgentParser($this->regexes);
    34|     }
    35|
    36|     /** Sets up some standard variables as well as starts the user agent parsing process */
  > 37|     public function parse(string $userAgent, array $jsParseBits = []): Client
    38|     {
    39|         $client = new Client($userAgent);
    40|
    41|         $client->ua = $this->userAgentParser->parseUserAgent($userAgent, $jsParseBits);

  1   C:\laragon\www\Portfolio\vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Support\UserAgentParser.php:25
      UAParser\Parser::parse()

  2   C:\laragon\www\Portfolio\vendor\pragmarx\tracker\src\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider.php:174
      PragmaRX\Tracker\Support\UserAgentParser::__construct("C:\laragon\www\Portfolio")
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: Try to run ```composer dump-autoload``` and than ```composer require```. Also maybe this can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553676/argument-1-passed-to-uaparser-parserparse-must-be-of-the-type-string-null-g

Comment: Updated the question with the error that dump-autoload gave me.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall UAParser ?

Comment: I can not reinstall it. If I try to run composer remove UAParser I get: uaparser is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
Package "uaparser" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
There is no uaparser in my composer.json I've just double checked.

Comment: @AndriiSukhoi If I write `composer require` then press enter so it is empty it is uninstalling some left on dependencies, but sadly it still gives me the install error.

Comment: @AndriiSukhoi  when I'm using composer require it is removing it:   Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 12 removals
  - Removing ua-parser/uap-php (v3.9.13)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argument 1 passed to UAParser\Parser::parse() must be of the type string, null given in laravel stats tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553676/argument-1-passed-to-uaparser-parserparse-must-be-of-the-type-string-null-g)